# Unable to call methods of a custom view (canvasview) from Activity or class

Tags: java, android

I'm unable to call methods of a custom view ("canvasview") from the Activity that sets the layout including the view. I can't even call canvasview's "getters" from the activity.

Also, I'm passing the view to a custom class (that does not extend Activity), and I can't call canvasview's methods also from my custom class.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

**GameActivity.java:**

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{

    private View canvasview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game_layout);

        canvasview = (View) findViewById(R.id.canvasview);

        // Eclipse displays ERROR con those 2 method calls:
        int w = canvasview.get_canvaswidth();
        int h = canvasview.get_canvasheight();
    (...)
```

**game_layout.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".GameActivity" >

    (...)

    <com.example.test.CanvasView
        android:id="@+id/canvasview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**CanvasView.java:**

```
public class CanvasView extends View
{
    private Context context;
    private View view;
    private int canvaswidth;
    private int canvasheight;

    public CanvasView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        this.view = this;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, 
                                 int old_width, int old_height)
    {
        this.canvaswidth = width;
        this.canvasheight = height;
        super.onSizeChanged(width, height, old_width, old_height);
    }

    public int get_canvaswidth()
    {
        return this.canvaswidth;
    }

    public int get_canvasheight()
    {
        return this.canvasheight;
    }
```

I'm quite confused with this :?

I also have another class (it does not extend "Activity") that receives in the constructor a reference to canvasview and is also unable to "resolve" it :?

Thanks, sorry if the question is too obvious, I'm starting with Java and those kind of things are quite confusing to me ...

**EDIT:**

While at bed (03:00AM), thinking about it, I've noticed that Eclipse marks the line as an error because the View object does not really have the method get_canvaswidth(). Only the child "CanvasView" method has it. Thus, my problem can be solved with **upcast**:

```
int w = ((CanvasView) canvasview).get_canvaswidth();
```

I mean that I receive a view as parameter, but as I now it's really a view child, I should be able to use upcast to call "child's" methods. Now eclipse does not generate errors **but** w and h always report 0 :-? . I've also tested of not using upcast as has been suggested in an answer, and sending and receiving CanvasView objects in the calls and I also get 0 for both :?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private View canvasview;
```

No matter what is stored in `canvasview` you can only call methods defined by the variable type.  You need to change this line.

```
private CanvasView canvasview;
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. Yes, you're right but sometimes you can't change that you receive a View parameter. Tonight, about 03:00AM, while I was at bed x'D, I noticed that my problem can be solved with upcast:   int w = ((CanvasView) canvasview).get_canvaswidth();    I mean that I receive a view as parameter, but as I now it's really a view child, I should be able to use upcast to call "child's" methods. Now eclipse does not generate errors but w and h always report 0 :-? . I've tested of not using upcast and sending and receiving CanvasView objects in the calls and I also get 0 for both :?

Comment: Accepted, but it was not really needed...  just upcasting is enough to get a valid reference... Anyway is technically correct and allows solving the problem so... Thanks!